# response.sendRedirect() gives HTTP ERROR: 400 BAD_REQUEST only in IE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

I'm using Google App Engine (Java) with Google Accounts for authentication.

I've created a servlet (processSignIn.jsp) that makes sure the account should be allowed in for reasons other than a valid Google account (invite approved, etc.).  If the code evaluates correctly, it issues a "response.sendRedirect(url)" to send the user to the URL specified by the "url" parameter.

If a user clicks this type of link:

```
<a href="<%= userService.createLoginURL("../processSignIn.jsp?url=" +
request.getRequestURI()) %>">Sign in with a Google Account</a>
```

Then signs in with their Google account, everything works ok with Firefox or Chrome but not with IE 9.  See the requests and responses below.

Note the difference between the two GET headers... FF does not contain the "../" but IE does.  I would like to continue using relative paths so I don't have to do anything odd for local dev testing.

What could be the issue?

Firefox Request:

```
GET http://www.[mydomain].com/processSignIn.jsp?url=/main.jsp HTTP/1.1
Host: www.[mydomain].com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: [my cookie data]
```

Firefox Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Content-Type: text/html
Location: http://www.[mydomain].com/main.jsp
X-AppEngine-Estimated-CPM-US-Dollars: $0.000138
X-AppEngine-Resource-Usage: ms=18 cpu_ms=0 api_cpu_ms=0
Date: Sun, 11 Dec 2011 02:58:06 GMT
Server: Google Frontend
Content-Length: 0
```

---

IE 9 Request:

```
GET http://www.[mydomain].com/../processSignIn.jsp?url=/main.jsp HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Pragma: no-cache
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Cookie: [my cookie data]
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: www.[mydomain].com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

IE 9 Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
X-AppEngine-Estimated-CPM-US-Dollars: $0.001025
X-AppEngine-Resource-Usage: ms=13 cpu_ms=32 api_cpu_ms=0
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Sun, 11 Dec 2011 03:00:23 GMT
Server: Google Frontend
Content-Length: 1292

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 400 BAD_REQUEST</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 400</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /../processSignIn.jsp. Reason:
<pre>    BAD_REQUEST</pre></p>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

That can only mean that the generated `<a>` element has an URL with `/../` inside which made MSIE and Jetty to choke. Please note that your JSP/servlet code wasn't even hit. It was Jetty who blocked the request immediately due to bad URI.

To solve the bad URI, just don't use context-relative URLs with `../`, but rather use domain-relative URLs. In your case that would be

```
<a href="<%= userService.createLoginURL(request.getContextPath() 
    + "/processSignIn.jsp?url=" + request.getRequestURI()) %>">
```

By the way, I wonder what that `userService.createLoginURL()` is supposed to do. It seems to do nothing special at all.